# How detect Fading Edge in End or Start of ListView?

Tags: android

I've tried so many posts here in `StackOverflow` but with no luck. My requirement is very simple. I have a `listView`. When scrolling the `listView`, I want to detect the `Fading Edge`, i.e.  I want to show a Log massage when the fading edge will be visible. How can I detect the `Fading Edge`?

****UPDATE: I found the solution. Here is my Solution.****

`STEP 1: First I extended the ListView as shown below`

ManipulateList.java

```
public class ManipulateList extends ListView {

public ManipulateList(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public ManipulateList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public ManipulateList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX,
        boolean clampedY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("***", "Over Scrolling: Fading Edge NOW Visible");

    super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);
}


}
```

Here you can See, I've overridden the `onOverScrolled` method to do my Own Task here.

`Step 2: "activity_main.xml" declaration with my modified listview`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.example.customlist.ManipulateList
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</com.example.customlist.ManipulateList>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`STEP 3: My main activity's onCreate Method shown Below`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ManipulateList listView = (ManipulateList) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    String[] swName = new String[] {"a", "b","c",
            "d", "e","f",
            "g", "h","i",
            "j", "k","l",
            "m", "n","o",
            "p", "q","r",
            "s", "t","u",
            "v", "w","x",
            "y","z","a","b",
            "c","d","e","f"
            };


    ArrayAdapter<String> swGAA = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, swName);



    listView.setAdapter(swGAA);




}
```

`STEP 4: ENJOY!`

Comment: I found the solution. If anybody needs help just knock me. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Please post the solution at the bottom of your question so that people who reach this page via Google know what you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Fading Edge" is referred to as an "Overscroll" effect.

Look at the [onOverScroll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#onOverScrolled%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) method.

EDIT: It isn't called OverScroll. It is called [EdgeEffect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EdgeEffect.html).

Comment: Thank you brother... Your guidence helped me to find out the real solution.